Tangent lines equal secant line
Consider a continuous function $f$ with exactly three distinct points
$$
x_1(m) < x_2(m) < x_3(m)
$$
with slope $m$, meaning
$$
\frac{f(x_3(m))-f(x_1(m))}{x_3(m)-x_1(m)}=f'(x_3(m)) = f'(x_2(m)) = f'(x_1(m))= m
$$
( mean value theorem guaranteeing another point $x_2(m)$ between the secant line with the same slope ), e.g. $f$ quartic.
I tried to visualize it:

when i want to draw a straight line with slope $m$ that touches $f$ at two points, corresponding to the secant line but also the tangent line in those two points, I can only do it once.
Why does this line exist and especially why does this line only exist for one single slope  $m$ ( and their corresponding points ) ?.


Bottom:
Tangents of $f$ in the points $x_1(m) < x_2(m) < x_3(m)$ with slope $\widetilde m$ are parallel lines but not for $\textbf{one specific value}$ of $m$ (see top picture), because then they correspond to the secant line AND two tangent lines.
I hope you understand what I mean. $\textbf{Please only hints to help me prove it by myself}$.
$\textit{Edit:}$ Rolle's theorem guarantees me two zeros of $\Phi''$, meaning I have one turning point in $(x_1(m), x_2(m))$ and another one in $(x_2(m), x_3(m))$. When a tangent passes the first minimum, graphically it has to touch the graph at one other point near the second mimimum (that line is exactly the "double tangent" we are looking for with $$\frac{f(x_3(m))-f(x_1(m))}{x_3(m)-x_1(m)}=f'(x_3(m)) = f'(x_2(m)) = f'(x_1(m))= m).$$ The slope $m$ of that line and, therefore, the corresponding points $x_1(m), x_3(m)$ (and also $x_2(m)$ because of mean value theorem) are unique. But how do I prove it formally?

Does it help to sketch its derivative?

@Narasimham I haven't tried this yet, but I know that $f'(x_3(m)) = f'(x_2(m)) = f'(x_1(m))= m$ equals the three intersections of the derivative with the horizontal line $m$. I want this line to also equal $\frac{f(x_3(m))-f(x_1(m))}{x_3(m)-x_1(m)}$ which is the average change in the area $(x_1(m),x_3(m))$, right? Is there a clear connection?

Too long for a comment. As you write, your curve could be the graph of a single variable quartic polynomial. Indeed let it be given by $y-p_4(x)=0,$ where $p_4(x)=a x^4+b x^3+ c x^2 +d x +e.$ A general quartic curve has $28$ bitangents. But this is simple enough to be rationally parametrizable: $(x,y)=(t,p_4(t)).$ We can then find the dual curve and its nodes directly. $(x,y)=(-\frac{p_4'(t)}{tp_4'(t)-p_4(t)},\frac1{tp_4'(t)-p_4(t)}).$
The implicitization is $27 a^2 x^4+(4 b^3-18 a b c+108 a^2 d) x^3 y+(-b^2 c^2+4 a c^3+12 b^3 d-54 a b c d+162 a^2 d^2+6 a b^2 e-144 a^2 c e) x^2 y^2+(-2 b^2 c^2 d+8 a c^3 d+12 b^3 d^2-54 a b c d^2+108 a^2 d^3-18 b^3 c e+80 a b c^2 e+12 a b^2 d e-288 a^2 c d e+192 a^2 b e^2) x y^3+(-b^2 c^2 d^2+4 a c^3 d^2+4 b^3 d^3-18 a b c d^3+27 a^2 d^4+4 b^2 c^3 e-16 a c^4 e-18 b^3 c d e+80 a b c^2 d e+6 a b^2 d^2 e-144 a^2 c d^2 e+27 b^4 e^2-144 a b^2 c e^2+128 a^2 c^2 e^2+192 a^2 b d e^2-256 a^3 e^3) y^4+(6 a b^2-144 a^2 c) x^2 y 1+(-18 b^3 c+80 a b c^2+12 a b^2 d-288 a^2 c d+384 a^2 b e) x y^2 1+(4 b^2 c^3-16 a c^4-18 b^3 c d+80 a b c^2 d+6 a b^2 d^2-144 a^2 c d^2+54 b^4 e-288 a b^2 c e+256 a^2 c^2 e+384 a^2 b d e-768 a^3 e^2) y^3 1+192 a^2 b x y 1^2+(27 b^4-144 a b^2 c+128 a^2 c^2+192 a^2 b d-768 a^3 e) y^2 1^2-256 a^3 y 1^3=0.$
When the curve looks like a w, this has two cusps and a node. The node corresponds to the single bitangent. As an example take $(a,b,c,d,e)=(6/10,22/10,14/10,13/10,33/10),$ then the dual is $2430000x^4+14968000x^3y-12490600x^2y^2+276369040xy^3+296908803y^4-13788000x^2y+199718400xy^2+62013320y^3+38016000xy-53096400y^2-13824000y=0$
with node $(21000/27143,-8640/27143)$ making the bitangent $21000x/27143-8640y/27143+1=0.$ 

HINT:
Some wavy curves with maxima, minimum and a tangent line:


Can you help me prove it mathematically? Graphically it makes sense... but I want to show that this "double tangent line" (coinciding with the secant of those two points) exists and is unique... I made an edit in my question to add some other observations I made

In $ x+ 2 \cos (x)^2+4 \sin (x)^2$ there is the monotonous part $x$ and the rest is the wavy fluctuating part. A little more effort is needed. Double tangent has 4 roots, two repeated.
